# C++ - Logistic Regression Backpropagation with Gradient Descent

Tags: c++, performance, c++17, machine-learning, numerical-methods

I implemented binary logistic regression for a single datapoint trained with the backpropagation algorithm to calculate derivatives for a gradient descent optimizer.

I am primarily looking for feedback on how I approached the functions that return optional derivatives. I used `nullptr` as a flag to indicate that derivatives are not needed, but was wondering whether the alternatives would be better (i.e., using a boolean flag, using an optional, using a non-const reference, etc.). The derivatives are optional since inference would not need the derivatives. I have left the forward pass functionality out to keep the code a bit smaller.

I am also interested in performance, style, and correct usage of C++ idioms. I am aware that linear algebraic methods would benefit from vectorized methods. For performance concerns, I'm more interested in things like needless copies and redundant computations rather than vectorization opportunities.

Note that I use the naming convention from Andrew Ng's Deep Learning course of the variable name `dVAR` in a function `f` to mean the derivative of `f` with respect to `VAR`. For example, in `double f(double x, double* dx)` `dx`\$ = \frac{df(x)}{dx}\$.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

template<int sz>
class Vec {
public:
  Vec<sz>() {}
  Vec<sz>(const std::array<double, sz>& storage) : storage_{storage} {}
  Vec<sz>(std::array<double, sz>&& storage) : storage_{move(storage)} {}
  
  Vec<sz> operator-(const Vec<sz>& other) const {
    std::array<double, sz> result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < storage_.size(); ++i) {
      result[i] = storage_[i] - other.storage_[i];
    }
    return Vec<sz>{result};
  }
  
  Vec<sz> operator*(const double scalar) const {
    std::array<double, sz> result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < storage_.size(); ++i) {
      result[i] = scalar * storage_[i];
    }
    return Vec<sz>{result};
  }
  
  double operator[](const size_t idx) const {
    return storage_[idx];
  }
  
  bool operator==(const Vec& other) const {
    return storage_ == other.storage_;
  }
  
  size_t size() const {
    return sz;
  }
private:
  std::array<double, sz> storage_;
};

template<int sz>
Vec<sz> operator*(const double scalar, Vec<sz> v) {
  return v * scalar;
}

// Computes the sigmoid function and optionally its derivative.
double sigmoid(const double x, double* dx=nullptr) {
  const double ret = 1 / (1 + std::exp(-x));
  if (dx) {
    *dx = ret * (1 - ret);
  }
  return ret;
}

// Compute the cross entropy and optionally its derivative with respect to y_hat.
double cross_entropy(const int y, const double& y_hat, double* dy_hat=nullptr) {
  const double ret = - (y * std::log(y_hat) + (1 - y) * std::log(1 - y_hat));
  
  if (dy_hat) {
    *dy_hat = (y / (1 - y_hat)) + ((1 - y) / y_hat);
  }
  
  return ret;
};

// Compute the dot product and optionally its derivative with respect to w.
template<int size>
double dot_product(const Vec<size>& w,
                   const Vec<size>& x,
                   Vec<size>* dw=nullptr) {
  double ret = 0.0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i) {
    ret += w[i] * x[i];
  }
  
  if (dw) {
    *dw = x;
  }
  return ret;
}

// Do gradient descent of logistic regression updating weights and bias in place.
template<int size>
double logistic_regression(Vec<size>& w,
                           double& b,
                           const Vec<size>& x,
                           const int y,
                           const int num_epochs=100,
                           const double learning_rate=0.001) {
  double final_loss;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_epochs; ++i) {
    // Derivatives.
    Vec<size> dw;
    double dz;
    double da;
    
    // Forward pass.
    const double z = dot_product(w, x, &dw) + b;
    const double a = sigmoid(z, &dz);
    const double loss = cross_entropy(y, a, &da);
    
    // Backward pass.
    w = w - learning_rate * (dw * dz * da);
    b = b - learning_rate * (dz * da);
    
    final_loss = loss;
  }
  return final_loss;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the `Vec` class: Every function in this class could be `constexpr`. (Especially `size()`.) At least `operator==` and `size()` could also be `noexcept`. `constexpr` and `noexcept` could *vastly* improve code generation in most cases.

(Not all of the functions should really be `noexcept`, though. `operator[]` probably shouldn’t be, for example, because it might fail for out-of-range indexes. That doesn’t mean you should literally throw an exception! A non-`noexcept` function doesn’t *have* to throw. You’re just leaving it as an option, maybe just for in debug mode (and in release mode, remove all exceptions for max performance). You should read `noexcept` as “this function can’t possibly fail” and anything else as “this function can fail, and *might* throw when it does (or it might not)”.)

```
Vec<sz>(const std::array<double, sz>& storage) : storage_{storage} {}
Vec<sz>(std::array<double, sz>&& storage) : storage_{move(storage)} {}
```

There’s really no point in the second constructor. Arrays are not moveable. The *contents* of an array might be moveable, but in this case the contents are `double`s, and those are also not moveable. So you have a copy-only container of copy-only stuff… the moving constructor above ends up doing exactly the same thing as the copying constructor, making it pointless.

```
Vec<sz> operator-(const Vec<sz>& other) const {
```

It’s generally a good idea to make your binary operations non-member functions—it’s generally a good idea to make as many things as possible non-member functions, for the sake of encapsulation.

The usual way to do this is to define the assignment versions of binary ops in-class, and then write the regular binary ops in terms of the assignment versions. Or in plain C++lish:

```
class Type
{
public:
    auto operator+=(Type const& t) -> Type&
    {
        // define += operation...
        return *this;
    }

    // rest of class...
};

auto operator+(Type a, Type const& b) -> Type
{
    return a += b;
}
```

So you should probably write an `operator-=` for `Vec<sz>`, and then define `operator-` outside of the class in terms of `operator-=`. (You probably want an `operator-=` *anyway*, for reasons I’ll explain later.)

```
Vec<sz> operator-(const Vec<sz>& other) const {
  std::array<double, sz> result;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < storage_.size(); ++i) {
    result[i] = storage_[i] - other.storage_[i];
  }
  return Vec<sz>{result};
}
```

`result` seems to be completely superfluous here. You store the calculation results in `result`, and then copy them into the `Vec<sz>`’s internal `storage_`… why not skip that step, and store the calculation results directly into the `storage_`? Like so:

```
Vec<sz> operator-(const Vec<sz>& other) const {
  auto result = Vec<sz>{};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < storage_.size(); ++i) {
    result.storage_[i] = storage_[i] - other.storage_[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

With C++17’s guaranteed return value elision, you can end up with no copying at all.

```
Vec<sz> operator*(const double scalar) const {
```

This is another function that would be better as a non-member. In this case, you also have symmetry going on:

```
template <int sz>
auto operator*(Vec<sz> const& v, double scalar) -> Vec<sz> { ... }
template <int sz>
auto operator*(double scalar, Vec<sz> const& v) -> Vec<sz> { ... }
```

You could make one or both of those a friend of the class, or define both in terms of a member function (perhaps named `scale()`).

`operator==` should also be a non-member, and it should come along with `operator!=`. (`operator[]` has to be a member, of course.)

```
double sigmoid(const double x, double* dx=nullptr) {
```

I’m not a fan of default arguments. They make *writing* functions easier, but *using* them harder… which is the worst kind of feature, because you only write a function once, but you use them many times.

Even worse, in this case you’re actually ruining the function by making it less efficient *for every possibly usage*. If I don’t want the the derivative, I still have to pay for the extra function parameter and the check. If I do, I’m paying for a mostly unnecessary check (branching is slow!).

And on top of all that, if you *don’t* try to cram all possible usage scenarios into a single function, you avoid the entire question of whether to use `nullptr` or `std::optional`, and make the function easier to use because you can return the derivative directly:

```
double sigmoid(const double x) {
  return 1 / (1 + std::exp(-x));
}

std::tuple<double, double> sigmoid_with_derivative(const double x) {
  const double ret = 1 / (1 + std::exp(-x));
  return {ret, ret * (1 - ret)};
}

// usage:
auto a = sigmoid(x); // when I don't want the derivative
auto [a, dx] = sigmoid_with_derivative(x); // when I do want it
```

The same idea applies to `cross_entropy()` and `dot_product()`.

```
double cross_entropy(const int y, const double& y_hat, double* dy_hat=nullptr) {
```

I’m guessing the `&` here is a typo, but just in case not: there’s (usually!) nothing to be gained by passing built-in types like `double` by reference.

```
template<int size>
double logistic_regression(Vec<size>& w,
                           double& b,
                           const Vec<size>& x,
                           const int y,
                           const int num_epochs=100,
                           const double learning_rate=0.001) {
```

Hm… okay, the last two arguments here are probably legitimate use case for default arguments.

As for the *first* two arguments… I’m really not a fan of “out” arguments, if that’s what `w` and `b` are intended to be. But I don’t know what the intended usage of this function looks like, so I don’t know if maybe this is one of the very, very rare cases where they make sense.

Assuming that isn’t the case, a better form for this function might be something like:

```
template<int size>
std::tuple<double, Vec<size>, double>
logistic_regression(Vec<size> w,
                           double b,
                           const Vec<size>& x,
                           const int y,
                           const int num_epochs=100,
                           const double learning_rate=0.001) {

  // ... everything else in the function is the same except the last line...

  return {final_loss, w, b};
}
```

or:

```
template<int size>
std::tuple<double, Vec<size>, double>
logistic_regression(Vec<size> const w_,
                           double const b_,
                           const Vec<size>& x,
                           const int y,
                           const int num_epochs=100,
                           const double learning_rate=0.001) {
  auto ret = std::tuple{0.0, w_, b_};
  auto&& final_loss = std::get<0>(ret);
  auto&& w = std::get<1>(ret);
  auto&& b = std::get<2>(ret);

  // ... everything else in the function is the same except the last line...

  return ret;
}
```

Just a few final comments:

It’s good that you’re not fussing over vectorization, because, really, compilers are smart enough to already vectorize your loops. Even in the case that you’re working with a compiler that’s not, it’s pretty trivial to signal you want a loop vectorized with intrinsics or OMP or other means.

You are correct worry that your biggest performance drain will probably be poor algorithms and/or unnecessary copying. I don’t see any obvious signs of redundant or unnecessary calculations, so you might be okay on that front. That leaves unnecessary copying.

You’re using arrays for your data types, rather than, say, vectors. That can actually be a performance pessimization, especially if `sz` is large. Arrays are non-moveable; they can only be copied. Vectors can be copied or moved, and moves are so fast they’re basically free. On the other hand, when vectors *do* need to be copied, the cost can be many times more than the cost of copying an array, due to the overhead of allocation.

Note that I’m not suggesting you should use vectors instead! I’m just saying that when using arrays, you can’t count on moves. Every move is actually a copy. So if you *are* going to use arrays—which is a perfectly sensible thing to do for reasonably small `sz`—you need to be very careful to avoid *both* copies *and* moves.

You note (via a tag) that you’re using C++17. That’s good! That works out a *lot* in your favour, because C++17 brought in guaranteed elision. What does that mean?

It means that for a function like this:

```
template <int size>
auto dot_product_with_derivative(
        Vec<size> const& w,
        Vec<size> const& x)
    -> std::tuple<double, Vec<size>>
{
    auto ret = std::tuple{0.0, x};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ret += w[i] * x[i];

    return ret;
}
```

used like this:

```
auto [z, dw] = dot_product_with_derivative(w, x);
```

there is only a single array copy done (when the array in `x` is copied into what will eventually be `dw`). All other temporary/intermediate values are elided away. This is guaranteed by the standard starting C++17.

The only place I can see where you (might!) have a superfluous copy is in the line:

```
w = w - learning_rate * (dw * dz * da);
```

That’s because `(dw * dz * da)` has to create a temporary `Vec<size>` (let’s call it `tmp1`)…

… and then `learning_rate * tmp1` has to create *another* temporary `Vec<size>` (let’s call it `tmp2`)…

… and then `w - tmp2` has to create *ANOTHER* temporary…

… when then gets assigned into `w`.

That’s *THREE* temporary `Vec<size>` objects, each of which requires copying an array of `doubles`.

A smart compiler might be able to elide away that third temporary… but why risk it? Why not write `operator-=` and do:

```
w -= learning_rate * (dw * dz * da);
```

But that still leaves 2 temporaries.

Is there any reason you want to force `(dw * dz * da)` to be calculated first? That creates a temporary `Vec<size>` that you then multiply with `learning_rate`.

Why not reorder your calculation as: `(learning_rate * dz * da) * dz`?

```
w -= (learning_rate * dz * da) * dz;
```

Now `(learning_rate * dz * da)` only creates a temporary `double`… not a temporary `Vec<size>`. A temporary `double` is basically free.

Then `(learning_rate * dz * da) * dz` creates a temporary `Vec<size>`. That’s unavoidable. Let’s call that `tmp1`.

And then `w -= tmp1` creates no temporaries.

So you’ve gone from:

```
// Up to 3 temporaries created:
w = w - learning_rate * (dw * dz * da);
```

to:

```
// Only 1 temporary created at maximum, guaranteed:
w -= (learning_rate * dz * da) * dz;
```

without changing the actual calculation.

Now, I’m not sure if a smart compiler could do that optimization on its own. I’m not sure how blasé optimizers these days are about ignoring your parentheses, or reordering built-in operations around user-defined operations. Your original line of code *might* be compiled without all those temporaries. (Probably will, to be honest.) But why risk it? Rewriting `x = x - y` as `x -= y` is an optimization as old as time—it’s why `operator-=` exists in the first place. And reordering your computation so all the `double` calculations get done first and then only a single `Vec<size>` calculation has to be done is also a trivial thing to do. Even if it ultimately makes no difference (because optimizing compilers are so smart these days), it doesn’t really cost anything.

Without knowing the expected values for the `sz` parameter of `Vec<sz>`, I can’t comment on whether using arrays is a good idea. If `sz` is fairly small, then sure. Even if `sz` ranges into a hundred or so, maybe, if you’re not making a ton of these objects. But past a certain point, trucking the arrays around will get so unwieldy that it might make more sense to use vectors. With vectors, you would pay a lot more at construction time, and if copying… but you get super-fast moves. Might be worth it, especially if the rest of the code is written to take advantage of moving.

Comment: My primary motivation for using arrays rather than vectors was to avoid the runtime check of ensuring the length of vectors are the same in each function. Is there a clean way to avoid having `if (x.size() != w.size())` and `(size() != other.size())` splattered in all functions that do operations on vectors?

Comment: Sure, you can keep the size as a compile-time constant/template parameter. Just make sure the size is set in the constructors, and then just never change it anywhere else—it becomes a class invariant.

Comment: Ah, I see the `sz` and `size` template parameters remain. I had it wrong in my head that those would go away with a refactor from `array` to `vector`!